# Sequlize how 'as' and 'foreign key' attributes affect to the relationship?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm learning sequlize.

I'm developing the system using migration mechanism. Which means I add foreign keys using the migrations.

I have two models namely `banners` and `restaurants`.

One restaurant can have many banners.
and One banner belongs to a restaurant.

So in my **restaurants model**

```
restaurants.associate = function (models) {
    restaurants.hasMany(models.banners, {
      foreignKey: 'restaurant_id'
    })
  }
```

in my **banners model**

```
banners.associate = function (models) {
    banners.belongsTo(models.restaurants,{foreignKey: 'restaurant_id'});
    banners.belongsTo(models.regions,{foreignKey:"region_id"});
  };
```

When I try this query

```
const pending = await db.banners.findAll({
            where: {
                status: 'pending'
            },

            include: ['restaurants']

        })
```

It gives me the error

> Association with alias "restaurants" does not exists

My question is why could this happen? and how `as` and `foreignKey` attributes affect to the association? and Where we can skip those attributes?

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In you case all you need is to define alias :**

```
// in your model file
banners.belongsTo( models.restaurants , { as: 'restaurants' , foreignKey: 'restaurant_id'});

//from your api
db.banners.findAll({
    where: {
        status: 'pending'
    },
    include: ['restaurants'] // <--- If name is string then it should be alias name

});
```

---

**If you dont want to define alias , you can also use it like**

```
include: [models.restaurants] // <--- you can also use this
```

Comment: Again you helped me. =) Thanks Vivek

Comment: @PathumSamararathna , Mine Pleasure , Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: could you please tell me how to achieve this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946774/sequlize-how-to-do-nested-joins