# Sequlize how to do nested joins

Tags: sequelize.js

I have four models. namely

1. images
2. restaurant_items
3. restaurant
4. item

**images.belongsTo (restaurant_items)**

Which means I can get all the **restaurant_items** table details associated with the **image** like this,

```
const all_approved_images = await db.images.findAll({
            where: {
                status: "approved"
            },
            include: ['res_item']
        })
```

But I want to get the **ITEM TABLE AND RESTAURANT TABLE details at the same time**

**restaurant_items belongs to restaurant**

**restaurant_items belongs to item**

I tried this

```
const all_approved_images = await db.images.findAll({
            where: {
                status: "approved"
            },
            include: ['res_item','res','item']
        })
```

This didn't worked. Says

> Association with alias "res" does not exists

of cause it doesn't exists with the **images** 
But it exists with the **restaurant_items**

There should be a way to link all this things.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go , getting data from nested levels :

```
db.images.findAll({
    where: {
        status: "approved"
    },
    include: { 
        association: 'res_item' , // <---- First Level
        include : {
            association: 'res' , // <---- Second Level
            include : {
                association: 'item' , // <---- Third Level
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks you sooooooooooooooooooooooo much. =D You save the day. I have one more thing to ask. =) How do I filter the association data set. alias 'res' gives me all the details about the restaurant but I want only the res_name column.

Comment: add `attributes : ['id','res_name']` after this line `association: 'res'`